# 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'numpy' in tf.function in TF 2.0

Tags: python, tensorflow2.0

Is there any alternative to `tensor.numpy()` inside of a `tf.function` in TensorFlow 2.0? The problem is that when I try to use it in the decorated function, I get the error message `'Tensor' object has no attribute 'numpy'` while outside it runs without any problem.

Normally, I would go for something like `tensor.eval()` but it can be used only in a TF session and there are no sessions anymore in TF 2.0.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have a non decorated function, you correctly can use `numpy()` to extract the value of a `tf.Tensor`

```py
def f():
    a = tf.constant(10)
    tf.print("a:", a.numpy())
```

When you decorate the function, the `tf.Tensor` object changes semantic, becoming a Tensor of a computational Graph (the plain old `tf.Graph` object), therefore the `.numpy()` method disappear and if you want to get the value of the tensor, you just have to use it:

```py
@tf.function
def f():
    a = tf.constant(10)
    tf.print("a:", a)
```

Hence, you can't simply decorate an eager function but you have to rewrite it thinking as in Tensorflow 1.x.

I suggest you to read this article (and part 1) for a better understanding of how `tf.function` works: https://pgaleone.eu/tensorflow/tf.function/2019/04/03/dissecting-tf-function-part-2/

Comment: Thanks. For sure it is explaining, but the problem is that `tf.print` doesn't really extract the value, which is what I need. I need to extract the value in order to insert it to a `numpy.array` which I would like to assign to the original tensor later, because `tf.assign` doesn't work for items of a tensor.

Comment: If you post the code I can give you more help. I just given a generic answer because of a generic question :) If you want you can open a new question showing the code after marking this question as solved